# Powershell V2 assigning returned value from query to a variable return NULL

Tags: powershell, odbc

I think Im doing something wrong,, Im trying to query a Postgres DB from Powershell 2, using ODBC,, the DB returns a string like this if I query using PGADMIN (Postgres GUI):

0/164DAAB0

Thats a HEX with two extra characters at the beginning.
I need to extract the HEX.

When I do and assign it to a variable, and I print the variable, I get nothing, empty.
I tried on a computer with Powershell V3 and it works just fine, but I need to make it work on PS2.
I hope somebody spot my problem, I think there is a different/better way to do this so my variable gets the string returned by the query.

The code is :

```
$MasterDBIP = "172.16.50.20";
$MasterDBPort = "5432";
$MasterDB = "database1";
$MasterUid = "postgres";
$MasterPassword = "postgres";
$MasterMasterDBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=$MasterDBIP;Port=$MasterDBPort;Database=$MasterDB;Uid=$MasterUid;Pwd=$MasterPassword;"
$MasterDBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$MasterDBConn.ConnectionString = $MasterMasterDBConnectionString;
$MasterDBConn.Open();
$MasterDBCmdCurr = $MasterDBConn.CreateCommand();
$MasterDBCmdCurr.CommandText = "SELECT pg_last_xlog_receive_location();";
$MasterDBResultCurr = $MasterDBCmdCurr.ExecuteReader();
$MasterUserTableCurr=New-Object system.data.datatable
$MasterUserTableCurr.load($MasterDBResultCurr)
[string]$MasterStringValueCurr = $MasterUserTableCurr.pg_last_xlog_receive_location;
$MasterDBConn.Close();
$MasterStringValueCurr;
exit (0)
```

Additiional info:

The command $MasterUserTableCurr | Get-Member
Returns:

```
   TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

Name                          MemberType            Definition
----                          ----------            ----------
AcceptChanges                 Method                System.Void AcceptChanges()
BeginEdit                     Method                System.Void BeginEdit()
CancelEdit                    Method                System.Void CancelEdit()
ClearErrors                   Method                System.Void ClearErrors()
Delete                        Method                System.Void Delete()
EndEdit                       Method                System.Void EndEdit()
Equals                        Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetChildRows                  Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relat...
GetColumnError                Method                string GetColumnError(int columnIndex), string GetColumnError(string columnName), string GetColumnError(...
GetColumnsInError             Method                System.Data.DataColumn[] GetColumnsInError()
GetHashCode                   Method                int GetHashCode()
GetParentRow                  Method                System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relationN...
GetParentRows                 Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string relationName), System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string rel...
GetType                       Method                type GetType()
HasVersion                    Method                bool HasVersion(System.Data.DataRowVersion version)
IsNull                        Method                bool IsNull(int columnIndex), bool IsNull(string columnName), bool IsNull(System.Data.DataColumn column)...
RejectChanges                 Method                System.Void RejectChanges()
SetAdded                      Method                System.Void SetAdded()
SetColumnError                Method                System.Void SetColumnError(int columnIndex, string error), System.Void SetColumnError(string columnName,...
SetModified                   Method                System.Void SetModified()
SetParentRow                  Method                System.Void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow parentRow), System.Void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow pa...
ToString                      Method                string ToString()
Item                          ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int columnIndex) {get;set;}, System.Object Item(string columnName) {get;set;}, System...
pg_last_xlog_receive_location Property              System.String pg_last_xlog_receive_location {get;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have  that environment so it's hard to answer but i'll try anyway. Just to clarify, when you execute:

```
$MasterUserTableCurr.pg_last_xlog_receive_location
```

You get back: 0/164DAAB0, and the value you';re after should be: 64DAAB0, right?

Can you paste the results of these commands?

```
$MasterUserTableCurr | Get-Member
```

And

```
$MasterUserTableCurr.pg_last_xlog_receive_location | Get-Member
```

Comment: Not exactly,,, If I run the query SELECT pg_last_xlog_receive_location(); with my GUI, I get something like: 0/164DAAB0  ,, so Im trying to do the same from Powershell, and I need that value inside a variable,, so 'later' I strip the first two characters and get the Hex. Im having problems assigning the returned value from the query, into the variable.
Im expected to type : $MasterStringValueCurr;  and get the string: 0/164DAAB0   but I get nothing (empty, blank),, and no error.

Comment: I added the additional info you requested on the original post.
The last command returned:
Get-Member : No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet.

Comment: Can you get the value with this? $MasterDBResultCurr = $MasterDBCmdCurr.ExecuteReader(); 
while ( $MasterDBResultCurr.Read() ){ $MasterDBResultCurr["pg_last_xlog_receive_location"] }

Comment: Sorry Shay,, with that command I get nothing, empty, the variable $MasterDBResultCurr has nothing inside.

Comment: Im really out of ideas with this issue.

Comment: What do you get for: $MasterUserTableCurr.pg_last_xlog_receive_location | Get-Member ?